# How do I know when Vulkan isn't using memory anymore so I can overwrite it / reuse it?

Tags: vulkan

When working with Vulkan it's common that when creating a buffer, such as a uniform buffer, that you create multiple (buffers 'versions'), because if you have double buffering for example you don't know if the graphics API is still drawing the last frame (using the memory you bound and instructed it to use the last loop). I've seen this happen with uniform buffers but not vertex or index buffers or image/texture buffers. Is this because uniform buffers are updated regularly and vertex buffers or images are not?

If you wanted to update an image or a vertex buffer how would you go about it given that you don't know whether the graphics API is still using it? Do you simply reallocate new memory for that image/buffer and start anew? Even if you just want to update a section of it? And if this is the case that you allocate a new buffer, when would you know to release the old buffer? Would say, for example 5 frames into the future be OK? Or 2 seconds? After all, it could still be being used. How is this done?

Answer (score 2):

> given that you don't know whether the graphics API is still using it?

But you *do* know.

Vulkan doesn't arbitrarily use resources. It uses them exactly and only how your code *tells* it to use the resource. You created and submitted the commands that use those resources, so if you need to know when a resource is in use, it is you who must keep track of it and manage this.

You have to use API synchronization functions to follow the GPU's execution of commands.

If an action command uses some set of resources, then those resources are in use while that command is being executed. You have tools like events which can be used to stop subsequent commands from executing until some prior commands have finished. And events can tell when a particular command has finished, so that you'll know when those resources are no longer in use.

Semaphores have similar powers, but at the level of a batch of work. If a semaphore is signaled, then all of the commands in the batch that signaled it have completed and are no longer using the resources they use. Fences can be used for extremely coarse synchronization, at the level of a submit command.

You multi-buffer uniform data because the nature of uniform data is such that it typically needs to change every frame. If you have vertex buffers or images to change every frame, then you'll need to do the same thing with those.

For infrequent changes, you may want to have extra memory available so that you can just create new images or buffers, then delete the old ones when the memory is no longer in use. Or you may have to stall the CPU until the GPU has finished using those resources.